# Shopware AdvancedSearch missing features

Tags: shopware6

after upgarding to version 6.5.5.2 , activating SwagCommercial plugin and setting `ES_MULTILINGUAL_INDEX = 1` search seems to work in some way.
I don't see the possibility to search on product custom fields, will it be possible in the future? I don't see any documentation or update on this matter.
In the past it was possible to search on specific custom fields, now on categories for ex. I see the possibility to activate the search on ALL custom fields.